# How do I get a Broadcom BCM4312 wireless card to work?

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

I am currently using Ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop , the model of my wireless chip is broadcom BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY .

I tried to activate the driver for the chip by going to `System -> Administration -> Additional Drivers` and activated Broadcom STA wireless driver.
But the laptop can't detect any wireless signal still.

Do I have to do any additional work to make the chip work ? Or how can I test if there is physical damage to the chip itself?

Comment: Is the computer already plugged in via Ethernet?

Answer (score 1):

I have BCM4312 and 10.10 as well.  You might want to try reinstalling the drivers, given that you have already restarted the computer to see if you receive a wireless signal. In a terminal:

`sudo aptitude remove bcmwl-kernel-source`

to remove the drivers and

`sudo aptitude install bcmwl-kernel-source`

to install them again.  Restart and see if they are enabled/activated in your 'additional drivers' menu.

Comment: I think it solves the problem.

Comment: It solved my problem! ;D

Answer (score 1):

(if the method above doesn't work - resolve "firmware missing" problem)
There's no need for ndiswrapper and Windows drivers, because the Linux driver already exists.

- If you don't see broadcom wireless device name, uninstall driver,
  restart computer, install driver and restart again until "firmware
  missing" message appears with wifi device name under wireless icon
  after clicking on it (gnome).
- If you haven't it, you must install a synaptic package manager from
  Ubuntu software center
- search "bcm" inside synaptic package manager
- mark for installation `b43-fwcutter`, `firmware-b43-lpphy-installer`,
  `firmware-b43legacy-installer` and apply, no restart needed. Your
  Wi-Fi led turns on immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you problem can be solved in a similar way to mine I had some time ago.
See the answer to this question for the steps I took to resolve it.

[Broadcom BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX Issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14970/broadcom-bcm4401-b0-100base-tx-issues)