# Wireless shows up as disabled on a BCM4312 wireless card

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 (dual booted with Windows Vista) but I'm unable to access internet wirelessly even though I can do so on Vista.

The output for `rfkill list all` is :

```
0: brcmwl-0: wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked
```

The output for `lshw -C network` is:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:24:e8:c2:20:c9
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:46 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f6004000-f6004fff memory:f6000000-f6003fff memory:f6020000-f603ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
```

- Broadcom STA wireless driver is installed, activated, and currently in use
- My laptop is a Dell Vostro 1520

Comment: Have you tried to see if there are proprietary drivers for it using 'additional drivers'?

Comment: yes the Broadcom STA wireless driver is installed, activated and currently in use

Comment: Can you update with make and model of your system? Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing any wireless networks?

Comment: Possible duplicate? - http://askubuntu.com/questions/33855/how-do-i-get-a-broadcom-bcm4312-wireless-card-to-work

Comment: sorry, i'm back now. thanks for trying, no i 'm not sure how to update,can i do from the command line

Comment: i'm using Dell vostro 1520

Comment: my apologies guys.  I still haven't resolved this wireless headache. I really appreciate all your attempt.   to help me and humbly implore you all for more assistance, thanks

Comment: @roadmr : I'm using a Dell vostro 1520 notebook

Comment: @cprofit : I'm not seeing any wireless, yhanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try this command on a terminal?

```
sudo rmmod dell-laptop
```

If so, then you're affected by this bug, which is exactly on a Dell Vostro 1520:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/701259

A permanent workaround (try ONLY if the rmmod command does fix the problem) is to run this command on a terminal, to add the module to the blacklist so it doesn't load when the system boots:

```
echo "blacklist dell-laptop" |sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: Thank you for that bug fixon my Dell vostro.  Itś been a week and more of searching for solution to get my wireless working and this input from roadmr solve it to a tee(pun intended).  Thank you everyone for all the support, you make having Ubuntu a joy, especially when things start acting up.  merci beaucoup; tack so mycket :)

Comment: Glad it worked. If you have a Launchpad.net account, I'd appreciate if you could access the bug I mentioned above and click on 'This bug affects 6 people. Does this bug affect you?". The more people are affected by it (and say so,), the higher the chance of it being looked at more actively. Thanks!