# How do I get network connection and WiFi working on Dell Inspiron 1520 and Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, dell, broadcom

When I booted from the USB key, it popped up a notification for additional drivers, and then it installed an ethernet driver so at least the ethernet cable worked. After I installed and booted from the hard disk, neither the ethernet port works nor the wifi adapter. The lights on the ethernet port are on. I go to System Settings > Additional Drivers and nothing is listed either.

`lspci` shows

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100 Base-TX (rev 02)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 801.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
```

I found this answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/15014/276841) but the file says it is autogenerated and will be overwritten. It didn't work anyways, even after rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I ran

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and let it run a few minutes. It locked up the terminal but after I rebooted, the ethernet port worked. Here are the instructions for wireless which I haven't tried yet. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

I used the open source drivers in the section `b43 - Internet access`. It locked up the computer when I tried the `Switching Drivers` section, but after rebooting, it worked.